# How do I resolve 'exit status 255' error message when running the following program?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-api-gateway

I wrote a small program to execute `aws apigateway get-rest-apis` query to get the details of the API's i have created in the AWSG. The first few times the program worked but then i kept getting the **Exit status 255** error. It's probably AWS blocking the program from getting the data. How do I resolve this issue ? Thanks

```
package main 

import (
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
    "runtime"
    "strings"
)

func execute() {
    out, err := exec.Command("aws", "apigateway", "get-rest-apis").Output()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("%s", err)
    }

    fmt.Println(" Command successfully executed")
    output := string(out[:])
    fmt.Println(output)
    
    }
    
func main() {
    if runtime.GOOS == "windows" {
        fmt.Println("Can't execute this on a windows machine")
    }else {
        execute() 
    }
}
```

The error message i got : exit status 255 Command successfully executed

Comment: You should also check `stderr` for errors output by `aws`. You're only looking at `stdout`.

Comment: This is what I got : 2020/08/14 16:07:35 cmd.Run() failed with exit status 255
exit status 1

Comment: I mean the `stderr` of the command, not your program.